# Regular Expressions to match files with speecial format

Tags: grep

I have the following names of files:
When x is a number (x could be number between 0 to 100)

```
fileX
fileXblabla
fileX.X
fileX.Xblabla
```

For example

```
fileX --> file1
fileXblabla --> file1blabla
fileX.X --> file5.3
fileX.Xblabla --> file2.9blabla
```

my question is how to match each one of the following kind of files under directory (by ls and Regular Expressions or something else)

For example

```
 fileX
```

Under directory we want to get all files like: file1 or file2 or file3 …..file100

```
 fileXblabla
```

Under directory we want to get all files like: file1bla or file2bla or file3bla …..file100bla

```
 fileX.X
```

Under directory we want to get all files like: file1.1 or file2.1 or file3.1 …..file100.100

```
 fileX.Xblabla
```

Under directory we want to get all files like: file1.1bla or file2.1bla or file3.1bla …..file100.100bla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^file(100|[1-9]\d|\d)(\.(100|[1-9]\d|\d))?(bla)*$
```

Comment: if you can please give example how to exe this syntax wilh ls command

Answer (score 0):

The following REGEX will match all 4 patterns:

```
file(\d{1,3})(\w*)(?:\.(\d{0,3})(\w*))?
```

The **X** in **fileX** will be in back reference **1**
The **blabla** in **fileXblabla** will be in back reference **2**
The **Y** in **fileX.Y** will be in back reference **3**
The **blabla** in **fileX.Yblabla** be in back reference **4**.

If you need any more help just raise add a comment.

Comment: This will match file number from 0 thru to 999.  If you want to limit it to 0 to 100 then replace the (\d{1,3}) with shinkou's (100|[1-9]\d|\d) modification.

Comment: how to write the grep with file(\d{1,3})(\w*)(?:\.(\d{0,3})(\w*))?

Comment: ls | grep file((\d{1,3})(\w*)(?:\.(\d{0,3})(\w*))? it dosent work

Comment: ls | grep  ^file(100|[1-9]\d|\d)(\.(100|[1-9]\d|\d))?(bla)*$
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
any help??

Comment: ls | grep "^file\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\([[:alnum:]]*\)\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}[[:alnum:]_]*\)$" This should work from a shell prompt (This is POSIX complient)