# regular expression to match files

Tags: regex

I used the following RE:

```
^file(\d{1,3})(\w*)(?:\.(\d{0,3})(\w*))?
```

To match the following

```
 file1.bla
```

or

```
 file1.1
```

or

```
 file1.1.bla
```

but after:

```
ls "^file(\d{1,3})(\w*)(?:\.(\d{0,3})(\w*))?"
```

I not see any match of the relevant files why?
Yael

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159725/regular-expressions-to-match-files-with-speecial-format which @yael also asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` only supports simple matching with ? and * and []

if you need to use regex, use find

```
find . -regex '.*/regularexpression'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ls -1 | grep "^file(\d{1,3})(\w*)(?:\.(\d{0,3})(\w*))?"` instead. This pipes the output of ls to grep, and grep filters the input (which is piped from ls) with the regexp.

Comment: You probably want ls -1, otherwise you will get multiple files per line.

Comment: @yeal, he gave you an example.

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is shell filename globbing (less powerful matching that REs) described [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/globbingref.html) and elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

ls -1 | perl -ne 'print if /^file(\d{1,3})(\w*)(?:.(\d{0,3})(\w*))?/'

(grep -P is supposed to use Perl regexp but on my system it doesn't seem to work. The only way to be sure you're using Perl regular expressions is to use Perl.)